# Backslash problems in R query string

Tags: r, rmysql

So, "\", is crushing my soul. I'm working on a query for `RMySQL` that requires some strange string escapes and I can't seem to find the right invocation of paste.

```
query <- 'CALL `storedprocX`(1, 30, "\'xyz-f43\', \'1002\'")'
```

My attempts so far have been close but I can't seem to get the literal backslashes in the right spot.

```
ids <- c("xyz-f43","1002")
x <- 1
y <- 30

paste0('CALL `storedprocX`(',x,',',y,paste0(" \\'",ids,"\\'",collapse = ","),')')
```

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with RMySQL but isn't the SQL engine taking care of escaping?

```
> esc.ids = paste(sprintf("\\'%s\\'", ids), collapse = ", ")
> esc.ids = paste0("\"", esc.ids, "\"", collapse = "")
> my.q = paste0("'CALL `storedprocX`(1, 30, ", esc.ids, ")'", collapse = "")
> cat(my.q)
'CALL `storedprocX`(1, 30, "\'xyz-f43\', \'1002\'")'
> nchar(my.q)
[1] 52
```

Would SQL not do the same cat does here?